# Stop terminal from trying to connect to docker

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and I was wondering how do I stop my MacBook terminal from trying to connect to the docker daemon after use. Every time I open my terminal application, I encounter the message:

"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? ()".

I tried quitting the Docker application on my device but my terminal is still trying to connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me as though Docker Desktop isn't installed correctly. Perhaps uninstall and reinstall again?